# Browse a nested structure in MySQL

Tags: mysql

My question is a little bit complicated, that's why I will use images to explain it:
Actually, I am trying to have a kind of nested structure for a GUI, using a MySQL database with the table below:[image]

This table could be shown as:
[image]

and what I am trying to do is to show only the elements, that has at least one green element as a child (could be not a direct child), as shown below:
[image]
I know that Recursive Queries in MySQL doesn't exist, and MySQL is not Hierarchical, even if it could be simulated as explained [here](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/mysqlbook/sampler/mysqled1ch20.html) .
Does anyone have any idea? (The number of levels is not fixe)

Comment: Is MySQL the only tool you have? Or are you performing these queries from an application? Because if you are using an application (well, developing one) you could simulate these recursive queries.

Comment: Only really 2 MySQL solutions. Either use a stored procedure to loop down through the child records of a record looking for a matching one. Or you use a nested set model (works well, but my experience is it struggles when inserting / deleting lots of records).

Comment: MySQL is all I have, so I think I will use a stored procedure as proposed by Kickstart. Thanks!

Comment: You can't write GUI programs with only mysql - you MUST have other tools at your disposal.

Comment: Of course, but I mean MySQL is the only choice I have for the DB, I am using PHP, JQUERY...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have extremely restricted in your technologies, use other technologies than database-native ones for such algorithmic tasks for applications.

Your particular case sounds like [Nested Set Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model), see more examples and discussions on SO:

- [How to insert data in the nested set model(MySQL);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373061/how-to-insert-data-in-the-nested-set-modelmysql)
- [SQL Query and PHP manipulation with Nested Set Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184598/sql-query-and-php-manipulation-with-nested-set-model)
- [Nested Set Model Php library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982067/nested-set-model-php-library)